# Couldnt communicate Client - Master SymmetricDs

Tags: java, tomcat, symmetricds

Hello i am triying to comunicate two machines, one virtual and my phisic machine, i am using SymmetricDs and i am new in the topic, after resolve a little bit errrors, i can make the comunication, but in the log of the tomcat there are some mistakes that i cant resolve.

1st error in TomEE Master:

```
[corp-000] - DataGapFastDetector - Full gap analysis is running
[corp-000] - DataGapFastDetector - Querying data in gaps from database took 4 ms
[corp-000] - DataGapFastDetector - Full gap analysis is done after 4 ms
[corp-000] - DataService - Queueing up an initial load to node 001
[corp-000] - RouterService -
org.jumpmind.db.sql.SqlException: usuario no tiene privilegios suficientes o objeto no encontrado: STORE_ID
        at org.jumpmind.db.sql.AbstractSqlTemplate.translate(AbstractSqlTemplate.java:300)
        at org.jumpmind.db.sql.AbstractSqlTemplate.translate(AbstractSqlTemplate.java:291)
        at org.jumpmind.db.sql.JdbcSqlTemplate.execute(JdbcSqlTemplate.java:493)
        at org.jumpmind.db.sql.JdbcSqlTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcSqlTemplate.java:156)
        at org.jumpmind.db.sql.AbstractSqlTemplate.queryForInt(AbstractSqlTemplate.java:63)
        at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.DataService.getDataCountForReload(DataService.java:990)
        at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.DataService.insertLoadBatchesForReload(DataService.java:938)
        at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.DataService.insertReloadEvents(DataService.java:491)
        at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.DataService.insertReloadEvents(DataService.java:368)
        at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.RouterService.insertInitialLoadEvents(RouterService.java:292)
        at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.RouterService.routeData(RouterService.java:211)
        at org.jumpmind.symmetric.job.RouterJob.doJob(RouterJob.java:49)
        at org.jumpmind.symmetric.job.AbstractJob.invoke(AbstractJob.java:225)
        at org.jumpmind.symmetric.job.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:287)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: usuario no tiene privilegios suficientes o objeto no encontrado: STORE_ID
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:281)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(PoolingDataSource.java:313)
        at org.jumpmind.db.sql.JdbcSqlTemplate$1.execute(JdbcSqlTemplate.java:163)
        at org.jumpmind.db.sql.JdbcSqlTemplate.execute(JdbcSqlTemplate.java:491)
        ... 19 more
[corp-000] - DataGapFastDetector - Full gap analysis is running
[corp-000] - DataGapFastDetector - Querying data in gaps from database took 7 ms
[corp-000] - DataGapFastDetector - Full gap analysis is done after 7 ms
```

2nd error in TomEE slave:

```
[store-001] - PullService - Could not communicate with node 'corp:000:000' at ht
tp://127.0.0.1:8080/SymmetricDsP/sync because of unexpected error
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://127.0.0.1:8080/SymmetricDsP/sync/pull?node
Id=001&securityToken=123456&hostName=WIN-V7LOLVN6KJ3&ipAddress=fe80%3A0%3A0%3A0%
3A0%3A5efe%3Ac0a8%3A2680%25net6
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor35.newInstance(Unknown Source
)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.
java:1944)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.
java:1939)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpU
RLConnection.java:1938)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLCo
nnection.java:1508)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLCon
nection.java:1492)
        at org.jumpmind.symmetric.transport.http.HttpTransportManager.getInputSt
reamFrom(HttpTransportManager.java:304)
        at org.jumpmind.symmetric.transport.http.HttpIncomingTransport.openStrea
m(HttpIncomingTransport.java:118)
        at org.jumpmind.symmetric.transport.http.HttpIncomingTransport.openReade
r(HttpIncomingTransport.java:125)
        at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.DataLoaderService.loadDataFromTra
nsport(DataLoaderService.java:567)
        at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.DataLoaderService.loadDataFromPul
l(DataLoaderService.java:296)
        at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.PullService.execute(PullService.j
ava:142)
        at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.NodeCommunicationService$1.run(No
deCommunicationService.java:519)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://127.0.0.1:8080/SymmetricDsP/syn
c/pull?nodeId=001&securityToken=123456&hostName=WIN-V7LOLVN6KJ3&ipAddress=fe80%3
A0%3A0%3A0%3A0%3A5efe%3Ac0a8%3A2680%25net6
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLCo
nnection.java:1890)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLCon
nection.java:1492)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480
)
        at org.jumpmind.symmetric.transport.http.HttpIncomingTransport.openConne
ctionCheckRedirects(HttpIncomingTransport.java:159)
        at org.jumpmind.symmetric.transport.http.HttpIncomingTransport.openStrea
m(HttpIncomingTransport.java:99)
        ... 8 more
[store-001] - PushService - Could not communicate with node 'corp:000:000' at ht
tp://127.0.0.1:8080/SymmetricDsP/sync because it returned HTTP code 404
```

If somebody know what i am doing bad, please help me

Comment: What's the sync.url in symmetric-ds.properties file at the store node? (I would avoid using master/slave notion, it sounds ugly)

Comment: The sync.url? There is only registration.url in the symmetric.properties at the store node, if you reffer to that is: http://10.255.2.142:8080/SymmetricDsP/sync/corp-000, and the Ip is the IpAdrress of my Master

Comment: my mistake, sorry. yes, I do refer to that url. the problem is that the store calls the corp on 127.0.0.1 (http://127.0.0.1:8080/SymmetricDsP/sync/pull?node
Id=001&securityToken=123456&hostName=WIN-V7LOLVN6KJ3&ipAddress=fe80%3A0%3A0%3A0%
3A0%3A5efe%3Ac0a8%3A2680%25net6). have you checked the hosts file if the ip 10.255.2.142 resolves to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Yes, if i put in my browser of the virtual machine 10.255.2.142:8080 that resolve to the page of Tomcat

Comment: yeah, but in your logs the ip address is 127.0.0.1 not 10.255.2.142

Comment: Exactly, i dont know why, thats weird because i check that file, and i see 10.255.2.142:8080 not the 127.0.0.1. There is another place where that is save?

Answer (score 3):

The first error indicates that the database user configured for SymmetricDS does not have the correct grants to access the table that was queue'd up for an initial load.